# Combinatorial meaning of a binomial expansion

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, cv.complex-variables, generating-functions

Let $F$ be a generating function $F(x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty f_i x^i$, and
suppose that we can do operations formally without worrying about
convergence issues.

Define the coefficients

\begin{gather*}
a_{n} := \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dx^n} \big(x^{n-1} \log F(x)\big) \rvert_{x=1} \\
b_{n} := \frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dx^n} \big(\log F(x)\big) \rvert_{x=1}.
\end{gather*}

**Question 1.** Then is it clear that $a$ and $b$ satisfy the
following binomial expansion relation?

$$a_{n} = n \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{i} \frac{b_{n-i}}{(n-i)!}$$

If so, what's a standard machinery that gives the equation? If
not, any hint on how we can get similar relation for $a$ and $b$?

**Question 2.** Is there any combinatorial meaning for the
aforementioned binomial relation?

---

#### Edit

Question 1 is very easy. The trick is not to be confused with $\log F(x)$ and just let $G(x) = \log F(x) = \sum_{k=0}^ \infty g_k (x-1)^k$. Then $a_n = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \binom{n}{k} g_k$, and hence the relation.

**Question 2 remains unanswered.**

Comment: Is it intentional that there's not anything being summed in your definition of $F(x)$?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Use Leibniz's rule for derivatives

Comment: It took me a while to understand the meaning of evaluation at $x=1$: interpreting each $f_k$ as a formal variable of degree $k$, any monomial in these variables appears only in a finite number of terms in, say, the $n$-th derivative of $\log F(x)$.  Thus, it may make it easier to phrase the question in terms of symmetric functions (or combinatorial species).

Comment: Maybe it would be better to phrase all of this using the more common $\log(1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1} \frac{x^n}{n}$ (which actually makes sense as a formal power series) and plugging in $x=0$ (which again is an operation that actually makes sense on formal power series).

Comment: @SamHopkins Thanks! I resolved question 1. However, the true question (2) is still mysterious..

Answer (score 1):

Using $t=x-1$ and $G(t) = \log F(x)$, it rewrites as
$$
a_n = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \frac{\partial^n}{\partial t^n} \left((t+1)^{n-1} G(t)\right)|_{t=0},
$$
and
$$
b_n = \frac{\partial^n}{\partial t^n} G(t) |_{t=0}.
$$
Assume that $G(t)$ is an exponential generating function of combinatorial structures of type $G$. Then, $b_n$ combinatorially corresponds to the number of labeled structures of type $G$ that use exactly $n$ atoms.

Conversely, $(n-1)! a_n$ is the number of labeled structures of type $(t+1)^{n-1} G$ that use exactly $n$ atoms. We can roughly interpret structures of type $(t+1)^{n-1} G$ as $n$-tuples, where first $n-1$ elements might either contain an atom or not, and the last tuple contains a structure of type $G$. How many such tuples are there so that the total number of atoms across all tuple elements is $n$?

Assuming that $i$ out of first $n-1$ tuple elements contain an atom, we have $\binom{n-1}{i}i!$ ways to choose them and assign labels from $1$ to $i$ to them. After that, we have $b_{n-i}$ ways to build a structure of type $G$ in the last tuple element and assign labels from $1$ to $n-i$ to its atoms. Finally, we have $\binom{n}{i}$ ways to join the labels and re-assign them values from $1$ to $n$ in a unique way. That being said, we get

$$
(n-1)! a_n = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{i} i! \binom{n}{i} b_{n-i},
$$
which is equivalent to the stated expression.

P.S. To interpret it in terms of $F(x)$, one could use the [exponential formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_formula) to argue that $F(x) = e^{G(t)}$ could be interpreted as an EGF for combinatorial structures corresponding to various sets consisting of structures of type $G$. Or, conversely, $G(t) = \log F(x)$ could be interpreted as a sub-type of $F$, consisting only of connected structures from $F$.

Comment: Thanks for the post! This teaches me to interpret any $\Phi^{(n)}(0)$ as counting labelled objects (with egf) in the future (very helpful)! However, could you make the "roughly" paragraph more concrete? I tried to recover but failed because polynomials $(t+1)^k$ does not seem to play well combinatorially when it is multiplied to an egf. It would be great if you could write $(n-1)! a_n$ as the cardinality of a specific set.

Comment: Generally, if you have two EGFs $A(x)$ and $B(x)$, then $A(x) B(x)$ is the EGF that enumerates pairs $(a,b)$, where $a$ is an object of type $A$ and $b$ is an object of type $B$. Thus, $(t+1)^k G(t)$ enumerates tuples of $k+1$ objects, where first $k$ objects are of type $(t+1)$ and the last object is of type $G$.

And for objects enumerated via $t+1$, we can interpret them as "either empty set (corresponding to $1$), or a single-atom object (corresponding to $t$)".

That being said, $(n-1)! a_n$ is the cardinality of the set of $n$-tuples, described as above.